# Tortoisesvn keeps saying "Please wait" after a huge refactoring

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have a Visual Studio project, where I did a lot of refactoring. It is not a huge project, but still ~3-400 files.

However, now I want to commit my code. Normally I can right click, "Commit", and then it works. But righ now, I get "Please wait..." in Tortoise:

[image]

I tried to let it run for 3 hours yesterday. It consumed 6gb of ram, but it didn't update.

So my question is: how do i fix this problem, so my code can be comitted?

Comment: Do you observe the same behavior if you navigate to the root of the working copy via Windows Explorer > Right-click | TortoiseSVN | SVN Commit?

Comment: Do you get output if you run `svn status` on the WC from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this was very weird. When I tried to commit on the root folder, I could not get it to work.

If I went into the subfolders and comitted a couple of folders at a time, it would easily find all changes and commit it.

Weird.

So basically the answer is: take smaller groups of files and commit.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the same problem, after just having copied a large source tree (with the .svn folder included) to a new computer.  I found this question in my search for a solution. The fix for me was the fix that usually fixes all ailments of SVN:

The ***"SVN Cleanup"*** command.

I did an *SVN Cleanup*, and after that, the commit dialog was *zippy*.